# Check Parent CheckBox on Checked Child in TreeView asp.net

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, treeview, parent-child

on one of the my webpage, i am using treeview (with checkBox) to display category, which sometime has deep hierarchy which means child-child-child and so on.. now what my requirement is when i check the child checkBox of the treeview, it should automatically check all the parents...

anyone please help me with some sample code.. i am really weak for treeview.

Comment: There are about 10 tree views that one can use in ASP.NET. Can you be more specific about your implementation.

Comment: @James Johnson: i was talking about asp:TreeView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If still relevant to anyone: [asp-net-treeview-checkbox-selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437617/asp-net-treeview-checkbox-selection) describes how to check children of a parent and parents of a child, using javascript. (Some answers check parents of a child, only if all children are checked.)